# Getting to grips with a basic JS for and if loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very basic loop that I currently don't understand fully.

```js
 for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i / 3) {
        $(".counterWrapper").append("fizz" + "<br>");
    }
    else {
        $(".counterWrapper").append(i + "<br>");
    }
 }
```

Basically I am wanting it to only return the word 'fizz' if the variable i's value is divisible by 3. Currently it is only returning the word 'fizz', so it would seem that it is getting stuck in the if loop and running it each time.

This is a very simple loop, but I think it might do with the way I am doing my comparisons. What would be the best way in order for it to work out if the variable i is dividable by 3?

Comment: You need to make a comparison in your if(). `if (i / 3)` isn't enough

Comment: In what way ? Surely this is only looking for if the i variable is divisible by 3? What would you need to compare it to

Comment: You need to see if the remainder of dividing `i` by `3` is equal to zero.

Comment: Essentially it's like saying, if i/3 is not null, then do this

Comment: Okay great, I am on the same page now. Thanks

Comment: Research the modulo operator

Comment: In your code, the if statement is saying "if 'i' divided by 3", but that's not a true/false question. It reduces to "if 1/3", "if 2/3", "if 1", "if 4/3", etc.

Comment: @factordog Your comparison is currently activating the code in the if statement block if i/3 is true, not if i/3 is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript true and false are treated uniquely. 0 is false, any other number is true. Take a look at:

```
if (i / 3) {
  $(".counterWrapper").append("fizz" + "<br>");
}
```

What you're saying is if i divided by 3 append fizz. So when looping:

```
if (0 / 3) // this would be 0 so it would be false
if (1 / 3) // this would not be zero so it is true
if (2 / 3) // this would not be zero so it is true
```

and so on.

You need to use modulo (%) which checks for remainders and use a comparison.

```
if (i % 3 === 0)
```

If you ran through the loop

```
if (0 % 3 === 0) // remainder is 0, so it is true
if (1 % 3 === 0) // remainder is 1, so it is false
if (2 % 3 === 0) // remainder is 2, so it is false
if (3 % 3 === 0) // remainder is 0, so it is true
```

Comment: Thanks for the input there! Helped me understand the way it works a lot better

Answer (score 4):

Your conditional is always going to be true. Use the modulus operator

```
if (i % 3 == 0) {
// print 'fizz'
}
```

Comment: I see. Is there not a way that it would be able to recognize that a number is able to be divided into the number that is stated within the if () ?

Your answer is obviously correct, but I was just wanting to see, as I imagine this is the correct way of creating a proper comparison mentioned by @joe8691

Comment: The modulus operator does just that. The modulus operator will return the remainder after division. So 5 % 4 = 1. In this way, any time i % 3 returns 0, it means that i is divisible by 3

Comment: @JustinHathaway it won't always be true. numbers can be used as true / false values in JS. It is false if i is 0.

Comment: @m4tt1mus You're right but the loop goes from 1-99 so the conditional will always be true.

Answer (score 2):

The value in your if statement isn't a valid comparison. Try using modulo and equality:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
    $(".counterWrapper").append("fizz" + "<br>");
    }
    else {
        $(".counterWrapper").append(i + "<br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: numbers can be used as true / false values in JS

Comment: @m4tt1mus Yes, but it's more readable my way.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( i % 3 === 0 )
```

This is a very basic question, with a very basic syntax issue.

Comment: Dont mind the downvotes. I am just trying to understand the basics. As I had been googling the correct method, but since i wasnt aware of the way to do a proper comparison I am then googling the wrong stuff

Comment: numbers can be used as true / false values in JS

Comment: To clarify, I did not down vote you. People don't like low effort posts.


You could try an introduction to coding tutorial for js. W3schools has some great examples: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp

Comment: Well from an experienced persons perspective it would seem like a low effort post. Being very new to it, its more that I did research, just didnt know what exactly to look out for :)